# Firefox getByteTimeDomainData assumes maximum wave amplitude when processing oscillatorNode output

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

Below is a simple snippet to demonstrate the problem.

In Google Chrome, setting `gainNode.gain.value` to an extremely low value like 0.01 will cause all `getByteTimeDomainData` data to stay relatively close to 128, as expected.

In Firefox, however, setting `gainNode.gain.value` to anything higher than 0 will cause values to vary between 0 and 255, as though the signal were as loud as possible.

```
var ctx = (new AudioContext() || new webkitAudioContext());
var oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
var processor = ctx.createScriptProcessor(2048,1,1);
window.waveData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
oscillator.start();

gainNode.gain.value = 0.01;

processor.onaudioprocess = function(){
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(waveData);
    console.log(waveData[0]);
};

oscillator.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(processor);
processor.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Is there any work-around in Firefox to 'emulate' Chrome's implementation and get the expected data?

My first thought was to populate an audio source with oscillator output, but I'm not sure how feasible this is, and it seems unreasonably ugly.

Comment: Not really an answer, but why would you want to use `getByteTimeDomainData` if you're already using a `ScripProcessor`. You can get access to the data using `AudioProcessEvent` which is the argument to `onaudioprocess`. http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioProcessingEvent-inputBuffer

Comment: You'd want to use getByteTimeDomainData to "sample" the data occasionally, rather than process every single byte.  It's more efficient.  Peter, this sounds like a bug that should get reported to Bugzilla.

Comment: @notthetup: As far as I can tell, `AudioProcessEvent` is not currently implemented in any major browsers.

@cwilso: Thank you, I suspect you're right, I'll submit a report at some stage in the next few hours.